# What is a set with exactly two elements called?

Tags: reference-request

A set containing exactly one element is called a **singleton**.

> Question: Is there a name for a set containing exactly two elements?

Comment: Occasionally it is called an unordered pair.

Comment: I've heard "doubleton" used a couple times, but I've never seen it in print. "Pair" I think might be confusing on its own since it suggests *ordered* pair, so "unordered pair" is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber THANKS - it does show up a few times on Math Reviews, so unless something else pops up, I will use it.

Comment: Dont forget about tripletons and dodecatons and all of the other ones.  Know your greek and latin prefixes.

Comment: What about $k$-set for $k \ge 1$?